# on page load grab php variable and send it to another page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this code is in page1 i have to send this variables to  page2 where 
i can get this variables using post method i have tried many to do but its so tough to it

```
calls();
function calls(){  

function calls(){
var l="<?php echo $abc ; ?>";
var u="<?php echo $cdf ; ?>";


var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "page2.php");
ajax.send("u="+u+"&l="+l);

}
```

this ajax variables have to be sent to page2 on page load automatically

Comment: calls(); function calls(){ <br/>

function calls(){ <br/>
var l="<?php echo $abc ; ?>"; <br/>
var u="<?php echo $cdf ; ?>"; <br/>


var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "page2.php"); <br/>
ajax.send("u="+u+"&l="+l); <br/>

} <br/>

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading page two anyway why not just use a form submit

```
   <input type ="hidden" value="$abc" name="l" />
```

Then just pick it up on page two

```
    $_POST['l']
```

Comment: suppose i'm user of page1 ajax takes the values of $abc and $cdf  php variables from page1 on page load and sends it to page2 where page2 is never loaded